# How do I add a shared library file to the java.library.path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, z3

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Eclipse version 2019-12 and OpenJDK 8 (as my current project requires version 8). The Java project can be successfully executed using this script:
[image]

Working in Eclipse, I want to add an external JAR file to the project, but I keep getting following exception:
[image]

I've tried the following:

**1. Adding the native library location containing all the shared libraries**
[image]

The depicted location contains the file "libz3java.so". Adding the same native library location to other JARs did not change the result.

**2. Setting the java.library.path via VM arguments**
[image]

**3. Adding an environment variable**
[image]

**4. Adding the prefix "lib" to the shared library filename**

This is the only way I was able to get another exception. I renamed "libz3java.so" to "liblibz3java.so" getting following exception:
[image]

"libz3.so" is another shared library found in the same directory. Adding the prefix "lib" to that library name doesn't change the exception.

How do I tell Eclipse where to find and read the missing shared library?

Comment: Start by checking if you can compile a Java program against z3 *without* using Eclipse. Does that work? If not, better fix that first.

Comment: Compiling and running JavaExample.java provided in the Z3Prover did not reveal any problems.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an environment variable, you have to explicitly use "/home/user/" instead of "~". However, I still don't understand why adding a native library or doing it via VM arguments doesn't work. I recall successfully linking the library as shown in my first attempt with the native library in newer versions (>4.8.6) of Z3 on Ubuntu 16.04.